# How to get the screen points of all the data points in AChartEngine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine to fill up the graph.

My biggest problem being to get the co-ordinates of each of the datapoints so that I can add my own drawables to it, in that position. I'm failing to figure out a way to get the screen points of the datapoints without firing up an onTouch listener. toScreenPoint is only effective if a screenspace is provided to it, and gives the values of the datapoint that has been touched.

How do I get the screen co-ordinates of all the datapoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the screen coordinates if they are actually rendered on the screen. If the points are not rendered, there are no screen coordinates available because the screen won't know the exact position your points are currently as they could have been moved as a result of pan or zoom operations.

`GraphicalView` has a method `getChart()` that returns you an `AbstractChart`. Just cast that to `XYChart`, as I am sure you need the screen coordinates in a chart that is an `XYChart` and then call `toScreenPoint(double[] realPoint)` where `realPoint` is `{realX, realY}`.